# Fluid suddenly disappears

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have a problem with fluids and I cant seem to find the answer.

I made a coffee mug which I want to fill with coffee. So I made a cylinder in the mug that turns into liquid when rendering. A little bit of the coffee gets spilled (as should happen if you manage to throw 21 cl as a drop in the mug).

But here comes the problem when the coffee gushes up and touches the domain ceiling, at frame 16, all the fluids in the domain disappears in the next frame. I looked in the domain and liquid object settings but I cant seem to find the problem.

Screenshot[image: Screen!]

Frame 16[image: Screen!]
Frame 17[image: Screen!]

Comment: So you used the cylinder as a 'fluid' object right and what shape is you 'domain' object? Could you add a screen capture? :)

Comment: @FacebFaceb The domain is a square but I deleted it's daces since they where blocking my view. Later I realised I could just hide it and facepalmed hard. Screen added to the OP.

Comment: And is the coffee cup set as an obstacle? What do you mean by 'disappear' in the next frame? Does the fluid become a cube or you can't see it?

Comment: As alternative of hiding, you could also press 'z' on the keyboard to view in wireframe

Comment: @FacebFaceb yes the mug is set as obstacle, it doesn't leak out the cup. I updated my OP with 2 more screens.

Comment: Did you already include these 2 screen captures? :)

Comment: @FacebFaceb something went wrong uploading the screens to imgur :/ try to refresh now.

Comment: Why do you change the start frames? ;)

Comment: @FacebFaceb So I can show those 2 frames without having to render all of them, and to see what impact my changes have on the frames where there error comes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25516/discussion-between-faceb-faceb-and-badatphp).

Answer (score 1):

The fluid is disappearing because the domain object is not "baked" completely. It's baked only until the frame where it's disappearing. Remember, the fluid is simulated on the domain object, so up until the frame, it's a fluid, and then it "turns back" into the domain object.

You need to bake the domain object and wait for that to finish before rendering.